# i wanted to change the font style of the content of a specific node after fetching and parsing the DOM tree

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have html for which I want to parse a specific node and change its content, along with making the font style of the new node value to italics. I am able to parse till the specific nodevalue but am not able to get how to change the fontstyle of the nodeValue.

In case of my problem

```
<html>
  <head>
  <script src="potrait.js"></script>
  </head>
 <body>
    <p class="q">Here comes the count</p>
    <ul class="q">
        <li><p class="q" align="center">1</p></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

i want to change '1' to one(something), (something) should be in italics.

I get till 1 using the DOM method shown below

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')
list[0].firstChild.nextSibling.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "one(something)")
```

I am able to change the content but I am not able to get how to change (something) to italics.

Any guidance would be really appreciable..!!

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrapping "(something)" in a italic tag ?

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName('ul')
list[0].firstChild.nextSibling.childNodes[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "one<i>(something)</i>")
```

Comment: I tried this..!! but i get the italic tag along with the word in my output

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `.innerHTML` and and an `<i>`:

```
var list=document.getElementsByTagName('ul'); 
var p = list[0].firstElementChild.firstElementChild;

p.innerHTML = "one<i>(something)</i>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to handle this problem easily. The code will be:

```
$("ul li p:first").html("one<i>(something)</i>");
```

That means take the first **p** tag within a **li** html tag in the **ul** and change its html content to `one<i>(something)</i>`. I have made a [Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/NEscQNa7sOmf04pbBIzM?p=preview) for you.

Be careful, because this code will replace all the first elements in your lists on your web page, where it has a **p** tag. To avoid that, you can assign to your desired **ul** a class. For example the list in your code has already have a class called *q*, so the code will look like:

```
$(".q :first").html("one<i>(something)</i>");
```

**EDIT:** To get a specific child(not absolutely the first) you can use `:nth-child(<number of child>)` insted of `:first`. For demos look at the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/).